# Display Custom comments field number

Tags: comments, customization

I have  some custom comments fields, I need to display the number of times that a meta value is used

Example :

I have a custom comments field "Do you like this post" with multiple choice :

- Yes
- No

I need to display how much person say "Yes", how much say "No" for each post, It's an example. Don't tell me to use "post rating" plugins ;)

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You want the number of times the meta_value is set, whether "yes" or "no"? The number of "yes" votes for all posts? The number of "yes" votes per post, or for a single post?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
$comments = get_comments();
$yes = 0;
$no = 0;
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    $vote = get_comment_meta ( $comment->comment_ID, 'vote', true );
    if ($vote == 'yes') {
        $yes++;
    } else if ($vote == 'no') {
        $no++;
    }
}
echo 'Yes:'.$yes.' No:'.$no;
```

Problem is the numbers can easily be manipulated so it might be better to count only one vote per user_id, comment_author or comment_author_IP depending on your usage.

Codex: [get_comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) - [get_comment_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_meta)